# Bartle's Elements of Integration Exercise 6.J

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

[image]

For the $(\impliedby)$ direction I'm gettinf it ok, but for the $(\implies)$ direction,
I'm getting the wrong inequalities. My ideas so far:
$$n\mu(E_n)=\int_{E_n}n\,dx\geq\int_{E_n}|f(x)|dx \implies \sum n\mu(E_n)\geq \sum\int_{E_n}|f(x)|dx=\int|f(x)|dx<||f||_1 $$
That doesn't work, neither:
$$(n-1)\mu(E_n)=\int_{E_n}n-1\,dx\leq\int_{E_n}|f(x)|dx \implies \sum (n-1)\mu(E_n)\leq \sum\int_{E_n}|f(x)|dx=\int|f(x)|dx<||f||_1  $$

Comment: why $\sum n \mu(E_n) \ge \int |f(x)|dx = ||f||_1 \ge \sum (n-1)\mu(E_n) = \sum n \mu(E_n) - \mu(\bigcup E_n)$ doesn't work? (last equality due to $\{E_n\}$ being disjoint and fact that $\mu(X)$ is finite)

Comment: @DominikKutek Ah, I see, great idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}n\mathbb{1}_{\{n-1\leq |f(x)| <n\}}\leq |f(x)|+1\tag{1}
$$

and that

$$
|f(x)|\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1}n \mathbb{1}_{\{n-1\leq |f(x)| <n\}}\tag{2}$$

Since the measure is finite, integrability of $|f|$ implies the integrability of $G(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}n\mathbb{1}_{E_n}$. Conversely, the integrability of $G$ implies the integrability of $|f|$.